# Wordpress categories list RSS feed

Tags: php, ios, rss, wordpress

I am developing an iOS App for a blog. I managed to parse the posts and their content using the RSS feed, that Wordpress provides.

Now, i want to get an RSS feed of categories, so when an user selects a category, to display that category's posts. According to the Wordpress codex, there is a way to retrieve all the posts from a category, but how can i get a list of categories, maybe with an identifier or something so i can get all the posts based on that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not try making use of [get_categories()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories)? You could parse that into an xml feed, and expose it at `http://yoursite.com/category-rss/` for your app.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the party, but any custom theme dev's out there that are looking for a PHP way to easily do the same... this worked great for me:

```
href="<?php bloginfo('rss_url'); ?><?php echo('?cat=XXX'); ?>"
```

Where "XXX" is the category ID for the respective category you wish to pull in.